# PyTest setup or teardown a variable

Tags: python, pytest

How can I re-instantiate a variable for each of my PyTests?

Specifically, I want to create a new `StringIO()` object each time.

My current code is this:

```
output = StringIO()

def info_to_string(text):
    output.write(text) 

def write_to_file(some_text):
    for row in some_text:
        info_to_string(row)
```

I need `output` to be set up each time there is a new test fixture.

Copy and pastable code to test:

```
from io import StringIO
import pytest


output = StringIO()


def info_to_string(text):
    output.write(text)


def write_to_file(some_text):
    for row in some_text:
        info_to_string(row)


def test_1():
    write_to_file(['hello', 'there', 'what', 'is', 'up'])
    print(output)
    assert output.getvalue() == "hellotherewhatisup"


def test_2():
    write_to_file(['nothing', 'much'])
    assert output.getvalue() == "nothingmuch"
    #This will error as the output is "hellotherewhatisupnothingmuch" if run after test_1
```

So I would need a new `output = stringIO()` for each test.

Comment: <small>Psst, it's pseudo code, not psuedo.</small>

Comment: How would you explain what you are testing without the fixture or pytest at all, with plain `assert` statements?

Comment: @EvgenyPogrebnyak updated question with copy & pastable code.

Comment: `write_to_file()` is code under test?

Comment: In this example, yes (In actuality, I am testing the output of my code, which I get from write_to_file, so I care more about the values of the output.)

Comment: Ok, but you need a functioning ```write_to_file()``` that is not connceted to any fixture, they are different universes - your code and your test, including fixtures. Let me elaborate in the answer.

Comment: @EvgenyPogrebnyak I know what you're saying, It's only there because i am monkey patching the actual `write_to_file` function which saves to a file. This is all besides, the point. Is there a way to renew the `output=StringIO()` for each fixture?

Comment: @EvgenyPogrebnyak actually, just delete that it is a fixture, the fixture does nothing.

Comment: ... other than obfuscating the intent of your question. )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Incase anyone sees this in the future, the way I did this was by creating a class, re-initialising it each fixture

```
class WriteToString:
    def __init__(self):
        self.output = StringIO()

    def info_to_string(self, text):
        self.output.write(text)


@pytest.fixture
def write_to_string():
    return WriteToString()
```

and changing the tests to:

```
def test_2(write_to_string):
    write_to_file(['nothing', 'much'])
    assert write_to_string.output.getvalue() == "nothingmuch"
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I quite understand your questions, but you can do something like below, which will create a new StringIO instance every time you pass it into your test function. If you want to return a different string every time, I don't think you're looking for a fixture, but just a generic function call that does the work for you.

```
import pytest
from StringIO import StringIO

@pytest.fixture(scope='function')
def info_to_string():
    output = StringIO()
    output.write('blah')
    return output

def test_something(info_to_string):
    assert isinstance(info_to_string, StringIO)
    assert info_to_string.getvalue() == 'blah'
```

Comment: Sorry Grant, that's not what Im looking for.
My test_function will call `info_to_string` multiple times at different places (I am monkey patching it as a substitute for writing to a file), so I need all the different times its been written to.

Comment: @AH - you probably need to elaborate in more detail about _I need all the different times its been written to_, the fixture provided seems a decent input to tests. I suspect your usecase involves a lot of things happening to the fixture inside the test, but that again begs for more clear example (maybe just as plain ```assert```'s) and, probably, evaluating your tests - as it is more common to see just one thing bieng setup/tested.

Answer (score 1):

I think the easiest way to test file writing operation is to use [tempfile](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/tempfile.html#tempfile.TemporaryFile).

But once `StringIO` is mentioned as a part of testing strategy my suggestion would be to split file writing into two parts. This gives a clean entry point for `StringIO` buffer.

```
from pathlib import Path

from io import StringIO
import pytest

# Separate your data export to 2 functions, one operating 
# with a filename, other with a file object. 
def to_file(filename, content):
    path = Path(filename)
    if not path.exists():
        path.touch()
    with path.open('a') as f_obj:    
        write_to_file(f_obj, content)  

# This is code under test. It must not be connected to your
# test code in any way, even if you have some version of "monkey-patching"
# in mind.     
def write_to_file(file_object, content):
    """Dump *content* list of strings to *filename* with *writer*."""
    for x in content:
       file_object.write(str(x))    

# This is test with StringIO buffer
def test_write_to_file_with_buffer():
    buffer = StringIO()
    # note you make several calls to write_to_file in one test, not across tests
    # this helps keep tests isolated/independent
    write_to_file(buffer, ['hello', 'there', 'what', 'is', 'up']) 
    write_to_file(buffer, ['nothing', 'much'])
    assert buffer.getvalue() == 'hellotherewhatisupnothingmuch'
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll use your code for the time being, but I'll leave the question open to see if it is possible.

With unittests, you would just create a setUp function that has `output = StringIO()` and `def info_to_string(text): nonlocal output; output= StringIO(); output.write(text)`... but there is no easy setUp in pytest.

Comment: Some finalising remarks: 1) other alternatives may include 'real' monkey-patching, but to me they feel overkill for an object under control, 2) I see pytest `setup_method` as identical to unittest `setUp`, no major obstacle there.